# How to store data when using a webservice?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, web-services, architecture

I'm developing a Flex app which is connected to a webservice - but I'm curious about what is generally best practice for handling the data locally.

My webservice provides fairly small XML docs containing all the details about a certain object - is it considered better to parse that XML into objects for use in my UI, or just store the XML and access it directly?

My instincts say the former, though I'm sure doing a lot of parsing / encoding XML objects that I'm wondering if I shouldn't just add and remove elements when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating an application beyond what is considered trivial (you decide on that), I would suggest creating an intermediate layer that transforms the XML into objects. That way you are not tight to the XML specific details of your backend and you will be able to replace the implementation with alternative technologies or with stubs for testing.

There are already some questions and answer on this subject, so instead of repeating myself and others I'll just link to them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825460/working-with-both-adobe-flex-web-and-desktop-application/4826098#4826098).

Comment: 'alternative technologies' is a good point, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree, I normally create objects ( stored in an array collection if needed ) and dispose of the xml object and http service after I have finished parsing the data. My primary reason is so that I have the data in a format useful to me internally without having to worry if the web service return changes in the future which might mess up my existing code if I pulled from the xml returned directly.